# New Teradata Stats features . Confused about a few things

Tags: sql, database, teradata, data-warehouse, sqlperformance

Here I am in the same quagmire , maybe a lot of you folks are / had been. Teradata 14.1's got Object Usage feature on . 
This column is 1 env. turns out be zero prolly because we upgraded  sometime ago but in another ( QA / test ) env. its got values .
`DBC.DBQLRuleTbl |  TimeCreated` 
`sel   TimeCreated  from DBC.DBQLRuleTbl where DBQLRuleTbl.UserID in   ( sel OU.DatabaseId from DBC.ObjectUsage OU )`
No rows in 1 env. 
What I am trying to do is find out stats that are not used. We got OU on only for past few months. 
So I when I use this Query to find out UNUSED stats I get the last col -1 because the RuleTbl has got nothing that matches the OU table.

```
        SELECT DBC.DBase.DatabaseName AS DatabaseName
          ,DBC.TVM.TVMName        AS TableName
          ,COALESCE(DBC.StatsTbl.StatsName
                   ,DBC.StatsTbl.ExpressionList
                   ,'SUMMARY')    AS StatName
          ,CURRENT_DATE - CAST(DBC.StatsTbl.CreateTimeStamp AS DATE) AS StatAge
          ,CASE
           WHEN DatabaseName = 'DBC'
           THEN -2  -- Logging Not Applicable
           WHEN DBC.StatsTbl.StatsType IN ('B', 'M')
           THEN -2  -- Logging Not Applicable on Temp tables (base and materialized)
           WHEN DBC.DBQLRuleTbl.TimeCreated IS NULL
           THEN -1  -- Logging Not Enabled
           WHEN DBC.DBQLRuleTbl.TimeCreated > DBC.StatsTbl.CreateTimeStamp
           THEN CURRENT_DATE - CAST(DBC.DBQLRuleTbl.TimeCreated AS DATE)
           ELSE CURRENT_DATE - CAST(DBC.StatsTbl.CreateTimeStamp AS DATE)
     END AS DaysStatLogged 
    FROM   DBC.StatsTbl LEFT JOIN  DBC.DBQLRuleTbl
               ON DBC.StatsTbl.DatabaseId = DBC.DBQLRuleTbl.UserID
              AND DBQLRuleTbl.ExtraField5 = 'T'   

          ,DBC.Dbase
          ,DBC.TVM      
    WHERE DBC.StatsTbl.DatabaseId = DBC.DBASE.DatabaseId
      AND DBC.StatsTbl.ObjectId   = DBC.TVM.TVMId
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT '1' FROM DBC.ObjectUsage OU
                      WHERE OU.UsageType  = 'STA'
                        AND OU.DatabaseId = DBC.StatsTbl.DatabaseId
                        AND OU.ObjectId   = DBC.StatsTbl.ObjectId
                        AND OU.FieldId    = DBC.StatsTbl.StatsId
                        AND CURRENT_DATE - CAST(OU.LastAccessTimeStamp AS DATE) < N
                     )
      --AND DaysStatLogged > N 

    /* I had to mute this criteria because  otherwise there will be no o/p for reasons mentioned above */

      AND DBC.StatsTbl.StatsId <> 0  
-- Do not qualify table-level SUMMARY statistics as unused
-- May get implicitly used but not recorded as used
and StatAge < N 

/* StatAge < N .I am not sure if this filter should be there- I added it to catch those stats that are as old OU. We dunno if stats older than OU ever got used before OU started */
                                     and databasename in  ( sel child    from  dbc.children where parent ='FINDB'  group by      1 )
    ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```

I am trying to get JUST THE STATS for FINDB cascaded and not system wide stats.
Given the fact that my Rule Table is messed up - doesn't the  query above come closest to fit the bill  
"Find me stats for ALL Databases under FINDB that have not been used since OU was turned on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is probably ok as it's to be based on [Identifying Used, Unused and Missing Statistics](https://developer.teradata.com/database/articles/identifying-used-unused-and-missing-statistics), simply check if it returns what you want.

But you're on TD14.10 and the *Stats Manager* portly in Viewpoint does all that (and more), if you don't use it, yet, you should start [Easing Into Using the New AutoStats Feature](https://developer.teradata.com/blog/carrie/2013/12/easing-into-using-the-new-autostats-feature)